# Scale cairo image surface

Tags: c, cairo

I have a `cairo_surface_t` image surface that contains an arbitrary sized icon, and would like to scale it so that it fits into a window that I am drawing into. The window has a `cairo_t` drawing context that can be painted into. Example code is below

```
cairo_surface_t *image;
double scale = cairo_image_get_surface_height(image) / window->height;
// Scale here
cairo_set_source_surface(cairo, image, 0, 0);
cairo_paint(cairo);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cairo_scale` API.
Example: `cairo_scale(cairo, scale_width, scale_height);`

I will do this like below:

1. Resize the image using any algorithm.
2. `cairo_surface_t *surf = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(resize_image_data, CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, resize_image_width, resize_image_height, image_stride);`
3. Create cairo_t object **cr**.
4. `cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surf, 0, 0);`
5. `cairo_paint(cr);`

Comment: That scales the entire `cairo_t` context, yes? I would just like to scale one image and then place it onto the context.

Comment: It means you want to put a small image on a large context. Am I Correct?

Comment: I would like to scale a larger image onto a smaller context, apologies for not specifying.

Comment: I have edited the reply. Please let me know in case of any confusion.